# Asymmetrical behavior of button text when setting alpha value

Tags: ios, swift

I've got a standard button and I want the text of the button to be replaced with an activity indicator when the button is pressed but it isn't working and I'm puzzled why there is this difference in behavior between:

```
viewDidLoad() {
   activityIndicator.alpha = 0.0
   button.titleLabel?.alpha = 1.0
}
@IBAction func onUserHittingSButton(_ sender: Any) {
    button.titleLabel?.alpha = 0.0
    activityIndicator.alpha = 1.0
```

This does not behave as I want nor expect - when the button is clicked the activity indicator appears but the button text remains. But with this:

```
viewDidLoad() {
   activityIndicator.alpha = 1.0
   button.titleLabel?.alpha = 0.0
}
@IBAction func onUserHittingSButton(_ sender: Any) {
    button.titleLabel?.alpha = 1.0
    activityIndicator.alpha = 0.0
```

When the button is clicked the activity indicator is no longer visible and the button text is.

Why is the behavior not symmetrical?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line of code:

```
button.titleLabel?.alpha = 0.0
```

Also the next line of code won't work as well:

```
button.titleLabel?.text = "Some text here"
```

To change a property titleLable, you should use setTitle. So there are two ways to make textLabel invisible:

```
button.setTitle(nil, for: .normal)
button.alpha = 0.0
```

Comment: "button.titleLabel?.text = "Some text here" doesn't exist anywhere in the code. Where have you got this from?

Comment: Just for example, buddy

Answer (score 0):

The `titleLabel` alpha / color is being animated by `UIKit` -- so your code *may* set the alpha value, but the animation is continuing.

You can confirm this by setting:

```
button.isHighlighted = true
```

in `viewDidLoad()` and then inspect the `titleLabel?.alpha` property. It should be `0.2`.

While it's generally not a good idea to mess with internals, this may work for you:

```
@IBAction func onUserHittingSButton(_ sender: Any) {
    button.setTitleColor(.clear, for: .normal)
    activityIndicator.alpha = 1.0
}
```